# Placing the toggle sidebar button on the sidebar toolbar

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a three column layout macOS application with the first being the sidebar. I have a button that toggles that enabling the user to hide the sidebar.

On Xcode and other macOS, the toggle sidebar button resides on the toolbar on top of the sidebar, and becomes part of the main toolbar when the sidebar is hidden.

For example, open sidebar on Xcode:

[image]

And when you hide the sidebar:

[image]

I have added the toolbar with the toggle sidebar to the view containing my sidebar, and another toolbar to the second column, but still toggle sidebar appears on the main toolbar, on top of the second column.

Am I missing anything? Here's the code:

```
    // sidebar view, first of three columns
    struct ContentView: View {
       @State var selection: Set<Int> = [0]
       var body: some View {
          NavigationView {
              List(selection: self.$selection) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: AllData()) {
                        Label("All Data", systemImage: "note.text")
                    }
                    .tag(0)
                    Label("Trash", systemImage: "trash")
                }
                .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                        Button(action: toggleSidebar, label: {
                                Image(systemName: "sidebar.left") }).help("Toggle Sidebar")
                    }
                }
          }
       }
       func toggleSidebar() {
            NSApp.keyWindow?.firstResponder?.tryToPerform(#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil)
        }
    }

// second column view, with the rest of the toolbar
struct AllData: View {
   var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
           List(filteredData) {
                // list items here.
           }
           .toolbar {
             ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                Button("Press Me") {
                    print("Pressed")
                }
             }
             ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                Button("Press Me too") {
                    print("Pressed too")
                }
             }
         }
       }           
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
 ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. When I add this to the toolbar on the sidebar, the toggle sidebar button get pushed all the way to the far right of the toolbar.

Comment: drag the sidebar a little wider :)

Comment: Only shows when I made it a lot wider.

Comment: did you see the picture is posted? you can also try `.automatic` instead of `.primaryAction`

Comment: yes, I tried all possible options, hence I asked the question here.
The issue is that I don't want to have it so wide, when you go below 150 minWidth, the button disappears. Try to get your bar a bit narrower

Comment: If there is no way to do this, when I'll have to probably live with a wider sidebar?

Comment: yes, if you go below width 150 the button (with its standard padding) just doesn't fit anymore and is moved somewhere else. you can't get smaller, this is how Apple wants it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `.frame` modifier on the sidebar then you are able to set constraints for minimum width, ideal width and maximum width.

I find a `minWidth: 148` ensures the sidebar cannot be collapsed to the point where SwiftUI shuffles the toolbar button off to the trailing edge of the nav toolbar and behind (need to click) the double chevron expander.

So your code might look like this...

```
    ...
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: self.$selection) {
                NavigationLink(destination: AllData()) {
                    Label("All Data", systemImage: "note.text")
                }
                .tag(0)
                Label("Trash", systemImage: "trash")
            }
            .listStyle(.sidebar) //<-- from iOS 14 and macOS 10.15
            .frame(minWidth: 148, idealWidth: 160, maxWidth: 192, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    Button(action: {
                        toggleSidebar
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "sidebar.left") 
                    })
                    .help("Toggle Sidebar")
                }
            }
      }
   }
   ...
```

PS. I note that the `.primaryAction` and `.status` modifiers both place the sidebar button in a similar position, although I've not tested this thoroughly or completed any research.